# List view threshold in reporting services integrated mode in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

In one of my sharepoint sites I have a document library with 7,000 document sets, if I count the files inside there are 21000 files in total.

In the beginning we had some views, but when they growth we had list view threshold issues. What I did was to remove some of those views and use search results webparts to get the results the user wants.  For me incrementing the threshold is not a solution because this document library grows fast, (2K per month)

This solved the problem for some time.

However, some users do require to export to excel to do pivots based on this data, the only way I can think of is using reporting services in integrated mode with sharepoint, because I can export reports to excel and then they can do pivots.

The question is, will I have the same threshold problem when I make a report based on list data?

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

I have exported files to excel with 600,000+ rows. If the data you are pulling out reaches a certain size you will have to transition to .csv files as excel too has a threshold. The main issues you will run into on very large datasets are timeout issues that can be managed by configuring your http and ssrs timeouts, however, this will lead to other issues including long running reports of 15+ minutes and bandwidth usage.

I would recommend testing your scenario with a simple report to pull your data and see where the limit is reached. Also, look into some filtering mechanisms using parameters to reduce the amount of data returned to the client. If it becomes unmanageable then you may want to look into SSIS or some of the data-warehousing features. SSRS also has cached reporting that can place the processing burden to off hours if real-time data is not a necessity.

Comment: thank you but I am more interested in details about the threshold limit from sharepoint, by default the list view threshold is 5000 items, does it affect the reports running against a sharepoint list.